# Python3 script as deamon (via systemctl) and its dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not a python developer.
I try to start a python web server script (https://github.com/rpiwalletui/qtum-ui) during startup of the machine (raspbian stretch).

I prepared a init-d script for that which seems to make a valid try but the python script reports missing dependencies.

If I run the python3 script directly, it works fine.
But trying to run it using the init.d systemctl script the script fails with the following log:

```
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting qtumui.service...
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi qtumui[12111]: Starting /home/pi/qtum-ui/app.py:Traceback (most recent call last):
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi qtumui[12111]:   File "/home/pi/qtum-ui/app.py", line 3, in <module>
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi qtumui[12111]:     from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, url_for, redirect, send_file
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi qtumui[12111]: ImportError: No module named 'flask'
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi qtumui[12111]:  failed!
Jan 11 17:05:07 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started qtumui.service.
```

This is the init.d script

```
#! /bin/sh

PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin
DAEMON=/home/pi/qtum-ui/app.py
PIDFILE=/var/run/qtumui.pid

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
  start)
     log_daemon_msg "Starting $DAEMON"
     start_daemon -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
     log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  stop)
     log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DAEMON"
     killproc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON
     PID=`ps x |grep qtum | head -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
     kill -9 $PID
     log_end_msg $?
   ;;
  force-reload|restart)
     $0 stop
     $0 start
   ;;
  status)
     status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE $DAEMON atd && exit 0 || exit $?
   ;;
 *)
   echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/qtumui {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}"
   exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Is there something, which can be done to fix this?

Comment: First you say systemctl, but then you provide an old SysV-style init script. Which is it? systemd doesn't use init scripts -- it uses [unit files](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files#exam-Managing_Services_with_systemd-postfix_unit_file) (which are, frankly, much more reliable; I'm not much of a booster of systemd -- I prefer [Runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/) -- but *any* process supervision system is better than SysV init scripts).

Comment: At the end I used a different script, but this was not the point.
In each case I was able to give `/etc/init.d/qtumui start` a try, and in each case I got the python script to execute but with dependency errors. 
As far I managed to resolve that issue, I am tuning it now a bit further in order to get the autostart working

Comment: @CharlesDuffy But thank you for the hint to use systemd which I tried now and which works as well. Will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I managed to find out why the dependencies are missing.
I installed the dependencies as user "pi" using "pip3", in which case the modules are beeing installed into `/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/`.

The init script runs as some other default user, probably root, that is why the script can not find the dependencies.

To fix this I need to change the init-d script to run as user "pi", but the script works as well if I install the needed dependencies as root

```
sudo pip3 install flask Flask-WTF Flask-QRcode Flask-Bootstrap
```

In this case the modules can be found as well in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/` it kind of work, because of some ownership conflicts but the service starts at least.